# Javascript history.back not working in iOS7

Tags: html5-history, back-button-control

Our app is developed in Hybrid method and we are using JQM framework. For page transition, we are used $.mobile.changepage method and for back navigation, history.back() and history.go(-1) has been used.

When opens in safari it is working but not working in iOS7 homescreen. If anyone help me in resolving this would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in IOS 7 regarding this. I have been looking into the same problem and found this:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/the-html5-scorecard-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-in-ios7/

*"Finally, If your app uses AppCache and you are managing state via hash or other mechanisms, the history object will never update, disabling history.back."*

We are building a backbone.js app, but the problems might be related?